# Why is the Symfony2 Voter unanimous decision-strategy looping through the passed attributes?

Tags: php, symfony

I implemented a custom Symfony2 Voter and would pass an array of attributes to the first parameter of the `denyAccessUnlessGranted` like so in my controller:

```
$attr = [
    'module' => 'userModule'
    'action' => 'edit'
];
$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted($attr, $this, 'Not authorize to edit user');
```

This works alright if the decision manager approach is set to `affirmative`. However when I shifted to the `unanimous` approach all of sudden things didn't work because of the way my custom voter is designed. I looked through the Symfony source code and found that the reason is because the method for determining the result of a vote for the `unanimous` approach loops through the attributes before calling all the registered voters (instead of simply passing them to the voters as is the case for the `affirmative` and `consensus` approaches).

Snippets of the `Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/AccessDecisionManager` are included below:

```
private function decideAffirmative(TokenInterface $token, array $attributes, $object = null)
{
    $deny = 0;
    foreach ($this->voters as $voter) {
        $result = $voter->vote($token, $object, $attributes);
        ...
     }
}

private function decideConsensus(TokenInterface $token, array $attributes, $object = null)
{
    foreach ($this->voters as $voter) {
        $result = $voter->vote($token, $object, $attributes);
        ...
    }
}


private function decideUnanimous(TokenInterface $token, array $attributes, $object = null)
{
    $grant = 0;
    // ***** THIS IS THE ISSUE: WHY LOOP THROUGH THE ATTRIBUTES ****
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        foreach ($this->voters as $voter) {
            $result = $voter->vote($token, $object, array($attribute));
            ...
        }
    }
 }
```

The one for the `unanimous` decision making is the third one. What's the reasoning behind having to loop through the attributes? This means I will have to recode my custom voter depending on what decision making strategy I use, which I find really strange.

PS: The details of the implementation of my custom voter is not really important to this question so I decided not to put it here.

PS #2: This isn't my code, this is code from the Symfony2 framework (https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/AccessDecisionManager.php). I just want to know the reasoning behind it so that I can use the Voter functionality correctly. I'm guessing the best people to answer this would be people who knows the Symfony2 source code intimately.

Answer (score 1):

Look at class [RoleVoter](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/ee363805249cf9b49289c5178ca58ec3cf6ba579/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authorization/Voter/RoleVoter.php).

Voter::Vote() returns VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED if **any** of the attributes passed as arguments is authorised (there is at least one allow vote). If there are many attributes and some of there are authorised and some not -  VoterInterface::ACCESS_GRANTED is casted anyway.

But unanimous voting need that **every** attribute is authorised (no deny votes); thus we need test every attribute separately.